# Data Transfer Between Remote Computers

Tags: c#, sockets

What I'm to do is simple transfer of data (string or bytes) from one computer to another.
I'm using sockets as the links between the remote computers.
I'm at the start of my project but the problem is that i can't make a successful connection between the computers.
I don't understand what IP Address need to be in the IPEndpoint, my computer IPv4? My router IP? i think that the problem n my code.
The purpose of it to have 1 client and 1 server, afterward i will develop it to much larger application but right now my code is:

Server:

```
class Server
{
    static byte[] buffer;
    static string data;
    public static void StartListening()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[100000];
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[2];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,16000);
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                    data = null;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        bytes = new byte[1000];
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(data);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client: I tried all three ip address that IPHostEntry contains, they didn't work either, im trying the client program from my laptop.
Code:

```
public static void SendData(string send)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("MyIPAddressThat in hostinfo Addresses[2]"), 16000);
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send);
                sender.Send(msg);
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }
            #region Catch
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
            #endregion
    }
```

The thing i want to you to focus is which IP address is needed computer or modem , and maybe why my program didnt work.
thanks one help.

Comment: +1 because giving a negative vote without comment is not nice ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error lies here :

```
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
```

Why are you binding IPAdress.Any to your end point? It should be the IP address that your server is located on.
Did you try passing the ipAddress as parameter like this?

```
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
```

Comment: I thought that IP address.Any results will be that any ip can connect to the server,i mean that any computer the client program will able to connect to the server(me)

Comment: The end point is your endPoint. Suppose you have multiple network cards(like many servers do) then you need to specify which network adapter(or ip address) the server needs to listen on. I think you could filter on the IP address of the client but you'd have to do that once the socket connection is made.

Comment: After i made some changes in this code, it work but only in my computer, when its in my laptop it doesnt work i think its because client IPaddress.

Comment: Are you sure that the network isn't blocking your calls? You might have a firewall or router between the 2 computers blocking port 16000.